# Classifying compound statements

Tags: c

The following is a single declaration statement:

```
int count, sum;
```

What about the following `while` loop?

```
while (count++ < 20) {
    sum += count;
    printf("Running total: %d", sum);
}
```

Is the `while` loop considered a single statement because its structure is: `while () {...};`, or is the `while` loop just considered an example of control flow that may have zero or more statements within it? In other words, how are the 'statements' classified in this structure -- would the above loop be considered one or two statements?

Comment: I suspect it's three statements. The `while(condition){}` statement can even have side effects when the code block is empty.

Comment: Declarations are not statements in C. They are their own separate grammatical category.

Comment: @EricPostpischil a statement is anything with a `;`, right? I thought even the empty-line `;` is a statement, no?

Comment: @EricPostpischil also, what about this? https://gyazo.com/03530850e95ba683cc61c8dbd8010302

Comment: @samuelbrody1249: That is wrong. The C standard defines declarations in C 2018 6.7 and statements in 6.8. In the formal grammar of the C standard, a *declaration* is either various declaration specifiers followed by a (possibly empty) list of declarators with initializations or a special `_Static_assert` declaration. A *statement* is a labeled statement, compound statement, expression statement, selection statement, iteration statement, or jump statement. None of those are declarations (and the compound statement does not end with a semicolon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [C99 specification](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), a while loop is considered an iteration statement (§6.8.5), which is one type of statement. A while loop contains a controlling expression and a single statement as its loop body.

A list of statements surrounded by a brace is called a compound statement (§6.8.2), another type of statement.

So, your while loop is a single iteration statement, which contains a single compound statement as a loop body, which in turn contains two expression statements.

Comment: @nneo -- thanks, would you want to annotate the `while` loop I've provided to show the breakdown of how many statements there are there?

Comment: The direct answer to the question "Is the while loop considered a single statement" is *yes*, the while loop is one statement (not two).

Comment: @samuelbrody1249: If you want to count statements recursively, there are four: the while loop, the compound statement it contains, and the two expression statements inside the compound statement. But, for grammatical and semantic purposes, it would count as a single statement.